# How do style Text view with different font and colour on string subranges?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to style my Text view such that string it displays has different colours for each of 2 words. I know I can just use 2 x Text with different style. But then I should keep this string words in separate state variables. But I consider whether it is possible to define different .font().foregroundColor() for different parts of string.

There are also cases when there is longer lead and we want only first sentence or first word to be bolded, and remaining text to have regular font.

Any idea how to achieve this in SwiftUI?

Comment: You might use attributed string this link may help you - http://www.gfrigerio.com/nsattributedstring-in-swiftui/

Comment: See also here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-combine-text-views-together

Comment: when you say textview do you mean the `TextEditor`? I wish to do this with that, instead of Text views

Comment: You can find other solution here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61671313/making-parts-of-text-bold-in-swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61671313/making-parts-of-text-bold-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 36):

You can alternate formatting on a String with a `ForEach` loop wrapped in an `HStack`, although that comes with its own issues. The following code will let you conditionally apply formatting based on the word's location in the string:

```
struct FancyTextView: View {

    let label: String

    var splicedLabel: [String] {
        return label.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)
    }

    var body: some View {
    
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<splicedLabel.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(self.splicedLabel[index])
                    .fontWeight(index.isMultiple(of: 2) ? .bold : .regular)
                    .foregroundColor(index.isMultiple(of: 2) ? .blue : .red)
            }
        }
    
    }
}
```

[image: String formatting example]

Unfortunately, this simple solution doesn't work with longer strings:

[image: Poor formatting for longer strings]

I thought recursion might be useful, but I couldn't think of a way to use recursion with SwiftUI's `Text() + Text()` syntax.

Still, you could modify the above code to only format the first word with a larger font and then you could use the `Text() + Text()` syntax:

[image: First word formatting]

This also removes the unpleasant formatting of the `HStack` and `ForEach` combination with text. Just change the body to the following:

```
Text(splicedLabel[0] + " ")
        .font(.title)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
    + Text(splicedLabel[1])
```

If you use this example, make sure you change the `maxSplits` parameter in `.split()` to `1` and check to make sure that there are at least two strings in the resulting array.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without `+`? In my version of XCode I get this: `Referencing operator function '+' on 'RangeReplaceableCollection' requires that 'some View' conform to 'RangeReplaceableCollection'` when trying to add two styled `Text`. Can't update XCode because old MacBook...

Answer (score 23):

If you want something like:

[image]

Instead of using an HStack, use the addition operator like this:

```
Group {
        Text("I am an ")
            .foregroundColor(Color.red) +
        Text("iOS ")
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .fontWeight(.heavy) +
        Text("Developer:")
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
    }
```

Comment: Inside a VStack this lays them out one after the other vertically not horizontally.

Comment: Indeed... So you can out HStack inside VStack.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple solution with SwiftUI:**

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(Text("Text with blue color").coloredText(.blue)) \(Text("Text with yellow color").coloredText(.yellow))")
            .padding(20)
    }
}

extension Text {
    func coloredText(_ color: Color) -> Text {
        self.foregroundColor(color)
    }
}
```

Comment: Elegant solution. Underrated.

Comment: *Note:* Since `coloredText` is an extension of `Text` anyways, so naming the modifier `colored` or `color` will result in a neater API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Text() + Text() with .reduce(), starting off with an empty Text("") variable. I you want to alternate a Text on with green and blue for subsequent words:

```
import SwiftUI

struct StackOverflowText: View {
    let text: String

    var body: some View {
        let segments = text.split(separator: " ")
        segments.enumerated().reduce(Text("")) { acc, pair in
            acc + Text(pair.1 + " ")
                .foregroundStyle(pair.0 % 2 == 0 ? .green : .blue)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    StackOverflowText(text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
        .padding()
}
```

Which gives you this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specific font and color you can use like below :

```
 VStack{
            Text("Your First Text")
                .font(.custom("Poppins-Medium", size: 12))
                .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: UIColor(red: 0.631, green: 0.678, blue: 0.769, alpha: 1)))
                
            Text("Your Second Text")
                .font(.custom("Helvetica-Medium", size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: UIColor(red: 0.631, green: 0.678, blue: 0.769, alpha: 1)))
        }
```

Comment: Layout breaks if one of the text is longer than the other though.