# How to display highlighted words using swift ui

Tags: swiftui

var str:String = "When I was ###young$$$, I thought ###time$$$ was money"
VStsck{
Text(str)
}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol0Pj.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61671431/12299030? Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/59531328/12299030?

Comment: thanks for answer , I know to use Text()+Text(), but my string is a variable, I only know that the characters that need to be highlighted are contained in ###$$$, and i use ios 14 swift5

Comment: Then you just need to parse it and combine result as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62111947/12299030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your string using regular expression and build `Text` based on found ranges:

```
struct HighlightedText: View{
    let text: Text
    
    private static let regularExpression = try! NSRegularExpression(
        pattern: "###(?<content>((?!\\$\\$\\$).)*)\\$\\$\\$"
    )
    
    private struct SubstringRange {
        let content: NSRange
        let full: NSRange
    }
    
    init(_ string: String) {
        let ranges = Self.regularExpression
            .matches(
                in: string,
                options: [],
                range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count)
            )
            .map { match in
                SubstringRange(
                    content: match.range(withName: "content"),
                    full: match.range(at: 0)
                )
            }
        var nextNotProcessedSymbol = 0
        var text = Text("")
        let nsString = string as NSString
        func appendSubstringStartingNextIfNeeded(until endLocation: Int) {
            if nextNotProcessedSymbol < endLocation {
                text = text + Text(nsString.substring(
                    with: NSRange(
                        location: nextNotProcessedSymbol,
                        length: endLocation - nextNotProcessedSymbol
                    )
                ))
            }
        }
        for range in ranges {
            appendSubstringStartingNextIfNeeded(until: range.full.location)
            text = text + Text(nsString.substring(with: range.content))
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            nextNotProcessedSymbol = range.full.upperBound
        }
        appendSubstringStartingNextIfNeeded(until: string.count)
        self.text = text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        text
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
HighlightedText("When I was ###young$$$, I thought ###time$$$ was money")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func hilightText(str:String) -> Text{
   var resultText:Text = Text("")
   if(str.contains("###")){
        let titleArr:Array<String> = str.components(spearatedBy:"###")
        for(title in titleArr){
            resultText = resultText 
            + Text(title.components(spearatedBy:"$$$")[0]).foregroundColor(Color.red)
            + Text(title.components(spearatedBy:"$$$")[1]).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        }else{
            resultText = resultText + Text(title).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        }
   }
   return resultText 
}else{
   return Text(str).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
}

struct View1:View{
     @State var title = "When I was ###young$$$, I thought ###time$$$ was money"
     var body : some View{
         hilightText(str:title)
     }
}
```

Comment: I found a simple solution, although it doesn’t look elegant